# Jquery slider - Show value from slider in several places on page

Tags: jquery, slider, jquery-slider

I have a webpage where the user uses the slider to select quantity for the item he would like to buy.

Depending on quantity selected in the slider, a unqie div with the total price will show. Now i would like to add another div with the same id, in which i will show quantity + a "buy [quantity] now" button.

How can i make 2 divs with the same id show at the same time? I believe that's not possible - but maybe there is a work around? It doesn't need to be 2 divs, it can be "2 " or "1  and 1 " aswell.

So, to sum up. I would like to display the jquery slider value in several locations on the webpage. How can i do that?

Here is the slider i use:
**[jsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tobbecokta/Uum8j)**

Regards,
Tobias

Comment: You cannot have 2 elements with the same ID. Ids are unique. Use classes or `data-` attributes instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use two IDs, in order to achieve your goals you should use class.

Isted of

```
<div id="1" class="colors"...
```

use

```
<div id="1" class="colors v1"...
```

in this case `v1` is your identification

And if you have two element with the same class with jquery you can use them like `$('.v1').show()`

According your code it seems like

```
 $('#range-start').change(function() {
        $('.colors').hide();
        $('.v' + $(this).val()).show(); //#-> .v
    });
```

And your divs must has class v1 ... v10

See here ***[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Uum8j/14/)***

Comment: Hi Anton, thank you very much. It works perfectly! So simple :)

I have one more question if you have the time.. Im trying to move around the dropdown list in the div, but when i to that with <margin> or <padding> the slider moves aswell. Is there a way i can place the dropdown list where ever i want to without it affecting the slider?

Comment: if you need to put one on some fixed place, you can use css position:absolute; top: 50px; left:50px (50*50 as example). These style you can add to wrapper div

Comment: Hi! Yes that i know, but i'm having a harder time moving the dropdown list... I can't get it to move independently!